# trigger 2 time php code for top up

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to have this function of topping up e-wallet. I managed to top up, however, I found out that the PHP was called 2 times and hence the number will multiply by 2 for even number and for old number it will multiply 2 times +1. Can I know how can I solve this problem? 
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76WSf.png) this is the problem i faced in the above link

**topup.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>


 <!--
    Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
    For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://mp08.mybitmp.org https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/home.js"></script>-->
    <script src="scripts/topup.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/home.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>-->
    <title>Community Connection</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">


        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Community Connection </h1>
            <a href="#" onclick="home()" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="logout()" data-icon="power" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="newitem">
            <div id="credits"></div>
            <input type="range" name="slidercredits" id="slidercredits" value="0" min="0" max="100">

            <input type="button" id="btnTopUp" value="Top Up">
        </div>

        </div>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="jqm-footer">

            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id='btnHome' href='#' data-icon='home'>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a id='btnSearch' href='#' data-icon='search'>Search</a></li>
                    <li><a id='btnFind' href='#' data-icon='heart'>Find</a></li>
                    <li><a id='btnNotification' href='#' data-icon='info'>Notification</a></li>
                    <li><a id='btnMore' href='#right-panel' data-icon='bars'>More</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**topup.js**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

(function () {

    $(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
        printheader(); 
        taskbar();
        sidebar();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
         // var slidercredits = $("#slidercredits").val();
        getcurrentcredits();

        $("#btnTopUp").bind("click", function () {
            topup();
        });
    });


    //Profile Section
    function getcurrentcredits() {
        var url = serverURL() + "/getcurrentcredits.php";

        var JSONObject = {
            "user_name": localStorage.getItem("userid")
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSONObject,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (arr) {
                _getcurrentcredits(arr);
            },
            error: function () {
                validationMsg();
            }
        });
    }



   function _getcurrentcredits(arr) {
        userid = arr[0].user_name;
        credits = arr[0].credits;

        $("#credits").html("My Wallet: S$" + credits);
        //    $("#Sideusername").html("Username: " + userid);
        //  $("#imgProfilePicture").attr("src", serverURL() + "/images/" + profileimage + "_s");
    }


    function topup() {
        var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
        var slidercredits = $("#slidercredits").val();
        alert("slidercredits" + slidercredits);

        //var credits = $("#credits").val();

        //   if (validate()) {
        //var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = serverURL() + "/topup.php";

        var JSONObject = {
            "user_name": userid,
            "credits": slidercredits
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSONObject,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (arr) {
                _topupResult(arr);
            },
            error: function () {
                validationMsg();
            }
        });

         url += "?userid=" + userid + "&credits=" + credits;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                topupResult(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        //}

    }


    //function _topupResult(arr) {
    function topupResult(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        if (arr[0].result == "1") {
            alert("Topup success" + credits + "-->>>" + slidercredits);
            window.location = "topup.html";

        }
        else if (arr[0].result == "0") {
            alert("Topup failed.");
        }
    }
})();
```

**topup.php**

```
 <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    error_reporting(E_ERROR);

    include("global.php");

    try{
     $conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
            $username = $_GET["user_name"];
            $credits = $_GET["credits"];


       $query = "update Users set credits = credits +  " . $credits . " where user_name = '" . $username . "'";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if (!$result){
            $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";        
        }
        else {
            $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>1)) . "]";        
        }


        echo $json_out;

        $conn->close();
    }

    catch(Exception $e) {
        $json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
        echo $json_out;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because function `topup()` in `topup.js` makes an ajax call to the top up url and then immediately afterwards you have this code which does the same thing again

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```